# sanitize and raw still showing html tags, Slim

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I have a comment data which contains html text, and I want to show the html renders without any tags inside.

I'm working with RoR and slim.

I tried `sanitize`, `raw` and `html_safe`. but all of them gave me the same result. they removed some html but I still see html tags.

data before using them:

```
&lt;img alt=&quot;User-added image&quot; src=&quot;https://rrrrr;amp;feoid=00N2400000H7Rxb&amp;amp;refid=0EM7E0000004FgN&quot; style=&quot;height: 333px; width: 500px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam
```

data after using them:

```
    = raw resource.comments
    = sanitize resource.comments
    = strip_tags "'#{resource.comments}'"
    = ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(resource.comments)
```

or

```
def formatted_comments
  h.sanitize(comments, :tags => [], :attributes => [])
end 

 = formatted_comments
```

result:

```
<img alt="User-added image" src="https://rrrrr;feoid=00N2400000H7Rxb&amp;refid=0EM7E0000004FgN" style="height: 333px; width: 500px;"></img><br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
```

Update:

I noticed that the rendered html tag contains the following.
`" my result of html tags here " = $0`
trying to remove it manually, all html was rendered!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to do it like the following

```
 CGI.unescapeHTML(text).html_safe
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. it might works

```
rich_text = "<h1 class='some', some_other='some'>This is sentense </h1>"

helper.sanitize(rich_text, :tags => [], :attributes => [])
```

Documentation for this is here
[sanitize_helper](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/sanitize)

Comment: it gave the same result in the question. I still see tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [`strip_tags`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-strip_tags) it will return you the result by removing all html tags

```
str = "<img alt='User-added image' src='https://rrrrr;feoid=00N2400000H7Rxb&amp;refid=0EM7E0000004FgN' style='height: 333px; width: 500px;'></img><br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam"
```

Use it in slim

```
= strip_tags str

#=> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam"
```

Comment: it's giving the original value again :D

Comment: what do you mean by `original value`

Comment: are you trying it on `&lt;img alt=&quot;User-added image&quot;`